is there an implementation for STM32F042K6T6 in nano Firmware Flasher
Firstly excuse my (maybe)dumb question, but i'm a newbee on the field of mikrocontrollers.
I try to get my hands on nanoframework. The chip i have available is a NUCLEO-F042K6 evaluation board. The chiip on it is STM32F042K6T6.
see https://os.mbed.com/platforms/ST-Nucleo-F042K6/ for more information
now i'am not available to load the right firmware with nanoff (the hole process is found here https://docs.nanoframework.net/content/getting-started-guides/getting-started-managed.html)
is there a compatible implementation for processor STM32F042K6T6?
Thank you in advance for your time
i wanna know if there is an implementation of STM32F042K6T6 for nanoff and if yes whats the name

Ask for recommendation is off-topic. I think you might want to read How to create an STM32 based community board or ask Microsoft.

@hcheung: because my knowledge in terms of mikrocontroller isn't big, i wanted to ask if someone has this already made and can the code share with me

There is no firmware for that STM32. For the F0 series we have the STM32F091 as reference.
FYI: the F046 hasn't enough flash & RAM to run nanoFramework.

I can't find any F046 product.  That footnote would be really useful if you mentioned what the absolute minimum Flash and RAM requirements are

To have a device capable of running a useful app with a decent deploy region: 128k of flash and 68k of RAM.
